# Importing matlab structure to python

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, numpy

I am very new to `Python`, and I have to make some changes to existing project at work. I am importing data from `Matlab` binary data file into my `Python` script.

lets say original `*.m` file contains something like this:

```
> Temperature=61.3
> 
> VibrationSamples=[76,75,76,77, ... a lot of samples, 78]
>
> save(filename.mat, 'Temperature', 'VibrationSamples', '-mat7-binary')
```

(This is the minimal example I can provide)

I import resulting `*.mat` into the python script using

```
> mat = scipy.io.loadmat(filename.mat)
```

After that I am able to access elements from my matlab structure by using

```
> variableA = mat('temperature')
> variableB = mat('vibrationSamples')
```

However I am confused with the result. If I try to print varialbeA, for given example it will come up with two-dimensional array. The output of `print variableA` is `[[61.3]]`. In `*.m` file it is clearly `float`.

Why is this happening. What is clean way to resolve it? I know I can just use

```
> variableA = mat('temperature')[0][0]
```

But this does not look appropriate.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: That's how MATLAB stores values isn't it? It doesn't have scalars, only arrays.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention, that I am a total n00b in MATLAB too. So what would be the appropriate solution? Address values with index[0] as I described in the question? Or do the cast like float() or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's just how MATLAB stores scalars. In the MATLAB data model, scalars are represented as 1 by 1 arrays.

So in Python you would pull out the value like this:

```
mat['Temperature'][0,0]
```

More information on the MATLAB side of this issue can be found here: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/math/empty-matrices-scalars-and-vectors.html#f1-86433

> **Scalars**
>
> Any individual real or complex number is represented in MATLAB as a
>   1-by-1 matrix called a scalar value:
>
> ```
> A = 5;
>
> ndims(A)        % Check number of dimensions in A
> ans =
>      2
>
> size(A)         % Check value of row and column dimensions
> ans =
>      1     1
> ```
>
> Use the isscalar function to tell if a variable holds a scalar value:
>
> ```
> isscalar(A)
> ans =
>     1
> ```

Comment: Good explanation. Exactly what I needed. I will only add, that for integers and floats, casting does the same job as addressing using indexes. For example, `float(mat['Temperature'])` will have the same result as `mat['Temperature'][0][0]`. This won'e work for strings though